# Is isolated points always boundary points? Is Discrete Topology consisting of isolated points?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Is isolated points always boundary points?

What happens in the discrete topology space? If the space is R with discrete topology s.t f(x) = 0 if x is odd natural number, f(x) = 1, x is even natural number, f(x) = 2, if x = 1.5.

Is this a discrete topology? Is x= 1.5 an isolated point? Is x = 1.5 a boundary point?

Thanks very much for help! I am very confused here..